# Run observable one after another in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have array of object with following data :

```
 [  
   {  
      "name":"Uber",
      "points":20,   
      "nodeName":"C=GB,L=London,O=Uber",
      "port":10007,
      "nodeType":"merchant"
   },
   {  
      "name":"Starbucks",
      "points":20, 
      "nodeName":"C=US,L=New York,O=Starbucks",
      "port":10010,
      "nodeType":"merchant"
   },
   {  
      "name":"KFC",
      "points":20, 
      "nodeName":"C=US,L=New York,O=KFC",
      "port":10013,
      "nodeType":"merchant"
   }
]
```

I want to loop through this array and show [determinate progress](https://material.angular.io/components/progress-bar/overview) bar with animation and also should see points increasing in view shown in below image.for `points` attribute and want to show it one after another. i.e first for Uber progress bar displayed which will load till 100% for points of uber. and so on for starbucks and then for KFC.

[image]

I have tried below code ,where `res` is my above array:

```
 res.forEach((v, i) => {
        Observable.timer(100).subscribe((i) => {
            let interval = Observable.interval(100).subscribe((i) => {
                this.percentageCom = (this.points / this.PointsAdded) * 100;
                if (this.percentageCom === 100) {
                    // this.isHidden = true;
                    interval.unsubscribe();
                }
            })
        });
    });
    let timer = Observable.interval(100).subscribe(() => {
        this.points++;
        if (this.points === 60) {
            timer.unsubscribe();
            // this.router.navigate(['/main/dashboard']);
        }
    });
```

and HTML :

```
<div class="vendor">{{merchantName|| 'Uber'}}</div>
<mat-progress-bar mode="determinate" value="{{percentageCom }}"></mat-progress-bar>
```

But above code not display my progress bar one after another as those things are asynchronous,some weird output being shown i.e. simultaneously displaying progress bar .
Is there any way to show above loader one after another for each element of array ?

**UPDATED**

My Use case is as follow :

- From service response I get Array of object as mention above
- Lets consider first item of that array of object. It has points 20; so in my View ,points should increase from 0 to 20(just like counter)
- So while this point increment happens till 20, I want to show percentage Progress bar for Uber in this case which will run full 100%.
- Once above 2 points complete for one object i.e. uber same should happen for next item in array of object.

Above are the steps that i want to implement. But as `interval` and `timer` are async, i am not able to run it one after another by looping abpve object.

I have messed up code there in timer and interval...somehow I couldnt get throuugh it !

Comment: What's the above code supposed to do anyway? Why you need `interval()` or `timer()`?

Comment: @martin because want to show percentage loader; i guess without interval i wont be able to show percentage loader

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I  don't exactly find the purpose of mocking that loading behavior, but I think that you are looking for something like this code snipped. I think too, and the example shows, that you can remove the points variable.. but I am not sure because I did not understand 100% the context on where you are.

```js
const res =  [  
   {  
      "name":"Uber",
      "points":20,   
      "nodeName":"C=GB,L=London,O=Uber",
      "port":10007,
      "nodeType":"merchant"
   },
   {  
      "name":"Starbucks",
      "points":20, 
      "nodeName":"C=US,L=New York,O=Starbucks",
      "port":10010,
      "nodeType":"merchant"
   },
   {  
      "name":"KFC",
      "points":20, 
      "nodeName":"C=US,L=New York,O=KFC",
      "port":10013,
      "nodeType":"merchant"
   }
];

Rx.Observable.from(res)
.map( (value) => {
    return Rx.Observable.interval(100)
          .scan((acc, curr) => acc + 1)
          .take(value.points+1)
          .map(currentPoints => {
              const percentage = (currentPoints / value.points) * 100;
              return {arrayItem: value, percentage: percentage}
          })
})
 .concatAll()
 .subscribe((data) => {
    console.log(data.arrayItem.name + ': ' + data.percentage);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.8/dist/global/Rx.umd.js"></script>
```

**Edit**: I edited the solution, now is in serie.

**Explanation**:

- First we convert our array into an stream. 'Observable.from(res)'.
- For every item on the array, now in the stream, we map it into an Observable.interval(100)
- We take that Observable interval and we count the times it emits with scan and we finish it taking only as items as point the array item have.
- After that we map an return the value with its current percentage.
- The concatAll() operator just concatenates the observable sequence we have.
- Finally the subscribe method only shows a console log of the result

Comment: when I run above code; all the merchants calculation happening simulteneously !

Comment: you want to wait for each one? in serie?

Comment: yeah..first ubers points should get added to 20 and percentage loader will be shown for uber then points should increment to 40 and for starbucks it should show loader then to 60 for KFC

Comment: @user1608841 I updated the solution, don't know if is this exactly what you expect.

Comment: Ok...I shall try this...but on first sight on code... percentage loader will only run once ? I need that should run for every object !

Comment: mmmm don't understand the part you said percentage loader will only run once. What are you meaning for percentage loader?

Comment: Consider I have 0 points now(in above image instead of 2500) ... Then I hit service...then I get above array of object...now...that 20 points should get add and it's increment should be seen on webpage ... likewise our counter incrementing automatically !.. and at same time while points getting added...a progress indicator... likewise it goes from 0 to 100% will those 20 points get added ...see determinant progress bar in angular material

Comment: Percentage loader means..a progress bar... Moving from 0 to 100%

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157815/discussion-between-llorenc-pujol-ferriol-and-user1608841).

Comment: can you explain me what exactly u did in that observable chain ? I am quite noob in rxjs as of now...

Comment: can you please explain me above observable things?

Comment: @user1608841 I posted a little bit of explanation, but it is difficult to understand observables with only explanation. I recommend you to paste that code into a jsfiddle and test it and see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think you are doing an interval in the wrong place. You should do this on http get, then your subscribers will catch changes on observables with intervals. What you are looking for probably is called **polling request** and is high frequencies here

[helpful article](https://edqv.ist/angular-2-using-observables-at-an-interval/), [related issue](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3349)

example component.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Service } from './service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.css']
})

export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private service: Service) { }

  ngOnInit() {

   this.service.getNewValue()
     .subscribe((res) => console.log(res));

  }

}
```

example service.ts file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'; // ! Dont forget to Import Observable !

@Injectable()

export class Service {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getNewValue = () => {
    return Observable 
      .interval(1000)
      .flatMap((i) => this.http.get("http://yourhost.com/api"))
  }

}
```

didn't test it but should fix your problem

Comment: Hi ..please see my updated question..how flatmap would help me in this scenario ? I am already getting data from my service..issues lies ahead of that

Comment: thats not the point. this examples was added only to show where to put interval. Sorry about that, this is not clear answer, but the point is that you probably looking for polling request. i will update my answer soon , Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new timer for each item. I don't think that is what you want.

I think you want something like this:

```
res.forEach((v, i) => {
    //Add the point here because this is where your processing happens I guess?
    this.points++;
});

//Move it outside of your loop
$timer = Observable.timer(100).subscribe((i) => {// $timer as a local variable. 1000/60 might be better as it will refresh for every frame.
    this.percentageCom = (this.points / this.PointsAdded) * 100;
    if (this.percentageCom === 100) {
        // this.isHidden = true;
        this.$timer.unsubscribe();
    }
});
```

Also, this will probably process so fast, you won't see it.

Comment: Please see my updated question. I want to implement just like what I have updated. but cannot run it one after another